# Issue with search functionality in Model Structure Panel of Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, forge

I am experiencing an issue with the search functionality of the Model Structure Panel. As a reference, I also tested my models using this configuration: https://github.com/wallabyway/federatedmodels-v7

I have two models loaded in the scene, A and B. A has one component called Columns. I open the model structure panel, type Columns, and hit enter. The model structure panel **shows** that all components, besides Columns, are hidden. **HOWEVER**, what actually happens in the viewer is that all components of A, besides Columns, are hidden **BUT** all of model B is *still visible*, even though the model structure panel shows that it should be hidden.

Is this expected behavior? Am I missing something in the configuration of the viewer that I should be doing?

If there is anything specific that needs to be done to support this workflow, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Good catch, Rachel. This is a bug in the viewer. I've been able to reproduce it, too, and will report it to the viewer team. Please stay tuned to the viewer [changelog](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/) to check when it's fixed.